# How to replace a particular character in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a folder of CSV files (~100) and every file has an unknows character that looks like this �. This unknown character is supposed to be a double quote ("). Because of this unknown char, I am not able to run my CSV to xlsx converter to convert my files to XLSX format.

I tried using the `csv.read()` function but it does not with the `replace function` as `csv.read()` return a reader object and replace does not work with this. How can I replace that character and write the replaced contents back to csv so that I can run my csv to xlsx converter?

example :
current file contetnts:
"hello�

Output after convertion:
"hello"

Comment: Do you control how the csv file is created?  It would be better to fix this at source.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import fileinput

with fileinput.FileInput("file.csv", inplace=True) as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace('�', '"'), end='')
```

Comment: I tried this but these are the errors I get. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    for line in file:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/fileinput.py", line 248, in __next__
    line = self._readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/fileinput.py", line 368, in _readline
    return self._readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 521-522: invalid continuation byte

Comment: It seems the encoding is broken and the byte at 521-522 isn't a valid utf-8 character. You could try finding out if the � is not just put there by a text editor to signify a broken character.

Answer (score 0):

The sed command is designed for this kind of work. It finds and replaces characters from a file.
Use this in a terminal.

```
sed -i 's/old-word/new-word/g' filename.csv
```

Your `old-word` should be the unknown character and `new-word` the double quote

Comment: I'd be more inclined to redirect the output to a new file rather than updating in-place, in case the result is not what I expect.

Comment: No, this did not work. The terminal was not outputting anything and the file also did not change.

Comment: sed -i 's/�/"/g' test.csv this is what I tried. But it did work with a text file.

Answer (score 0):

I use this little function to deal with such problems.
The code is quite self-explanatory. It opens a file, read it all (may not work for files larger than your RAM) then rewrites it with a patched version.

```
def patch_file(file, original, patch):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        for line in lines:
            f.write(line.replace(original, patch))
            

patch_file(file='yourCSVfile.txt', original='�', patch'"')
```

Comment: Reading the file is the main issue. the error occues while reading the csv file it says encoder error.

Comment: Try changing the encoding `with open(file, 'r', econding='latin')` You can also set a ignore/replace in case of errors `with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as f:`

Comment: If you can share one of the files, I can be of more help.